# Why  a.compareTo(b) is equal to compareTo(a,b) or a.method(b) = method(a,b)?

Tags: c#

As i am new to C# programming language i am a little confused about C# syntax.

A method which can get two values to compare those two values can be written as `a.compareTo(b)`  instead of `compareTo(a,b)` How is it possible?

Assuming that `compareTo` returning an `int` the variable `a` is chained to `int` and gets compared! How?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C#, the `int` keyword actually represents a structure of type `System.Int32`. This type has several methods available on it, one of those being `CompareTo(Int32)` as you have seen.

`CompareTo` for an `Int32` object takes in an integer value, compares that value to itself and returns the result, very simply like this:

```
public int CompareTo(int value)
{
    if (this < value)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    if (this > value)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The `this` keyword refers to the current instance of the Type that this method belongs to, in your case `a`.

The documentation for `Int32` and its methods can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.aspx).

Comment: tnx for ur answer but what i am stuck with isnt the comparTo method. i want to know how it is possible for a method like this" int Sum(int a, int b) { return a + b) " be called by this syntax a.sum(b) instead of sum(a,b)

Comment: Are you familiar with the `this` syntax and the context of a method running on an instance of a class? What language are you coming from, or is C# your first?

Answer (score 0):

As per [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.compareto.aspx):

> This method is only a definition and must be implemented by a specific class or value type to have effect. The meaning of the comparisons specified in the Return Value section ("precedes", "occurs in the same position as", and "follows") depends on the particular implementation.

In the example, they compare temperatures by its Fahrenheit value which is a double:

```
public int CompareTo(object obj) {
    if (obj == null) return 1;

    Temperature otherTemperature = obj as Temperature;
    if (otherTemperature != null) 
        return this.temperatureF.CompareTo(otherTemperature.temperatureF);
    else
       throw new ArgumentException("Object is not a Temperature");
}
```

But in your own class, you can decide how to compare one instance of it against another.